# I want to python image data crawling on JSP Web page

Tags: jsp

I want to python image data crawling on JSP Web page. 
I want to know if this is possible.
If this is possible which method should I use?

My web page is use Apache Tomcat server.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is possible to crawl image data from a JSP web page using Python. To achieve this, you can utilize libraries such as Beautiful Soup and Requests to fetch the HTML content of the web page. Once you have the HTML, you can extract the image URLs using CSS selectors or regular expressions.

Here's a basic approach to get you started:

1-Install the required libraries:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4 requests
```

2-Import the necessary modules in your Python script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
```

3-Fetch the HTML content of the JSP web page:

```
url = 'http://your-web-page-url'
response = requests.get(url)
html_content = response.text
```

4-Parse the HTML using Beautiful Soup and extract the image URLs:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
images = soup.find_all('img')
image_urls = [img['src'] for img in images]
```

You can then process the "image_urls" list as needed, for example, by downloading the images or performing any other operations.

Remember to handle exceptions and customize the code according to your specific requirements. Additionally, ensure that you have the necessary permissions and rights to crawl and use the image data from the web page.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT